# Export QGIS shapefile with label

Tags: label, geoserver, qgis

How can I export a Shapefile in QGIS with its label ?
I've edited my layer with labels but when exporting it as a shape file, the labels diappear when I open it in Geoserver

Comment: In order to use shapefiles with labels in GeoServer you will have to use SLD.  More informations are available [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/)

Comment: @KcYoosuf  Yeah. But the problem is that the labels in the SLD disappear when I export the SLD in Geoserver. Everything stays but the labels disappear

Comment: As of [here](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/8925) , I think its an issue in QGIS. You will have to write your own SLD or use applications like uDig

Comment: Add your sld to the question and we may be able to help

Comment: @iant no need. After looking it up I understaood that Qgis does not support labels on SLD when the SLD is exported to Geoserver. BUT uDig does. So now I'm using a combination of both : SHP filefe from Qgis and SLD from uDig. I fits my needs.  Thanks Guyz

Comment: @Kurt please add your final solution as an answer to help others trying to find a solution.

Comment: @iant  That's true. Thank you for reminding me about that. I've posted my solution. Actually KcYoosuf should have written this answer (see his comment earlier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally here's what I found :

- The problem is not related to Geoserver ;
- After chating on IRC, an looking at gis.stackexchange.com, and finding this http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8925  it seems that this is a known issue for QGIS. 
  QGIS doesn't support labels on the SLD it generates.

**SOLUTIONS**

- There are two thing one can do if labelling is necessary :

  - The easy way (it worked for me) is to use uDig (another GIS software). With uDig, from my experience and point of view, you don't have a lot of editing options like QGIS BUT **uDig supports labels on its SLD files** when they are exported outside of it...(in my case I wanted to export and use them in Geoserver). **You can then use a combination of QGIS (to edit your shapefiles) and uDig( to edit SLD on the QGIS shapefiles)**...or only use uDig if you want.
  - The other way (I did not test it) : I got from IRC chat that one could use OsGeo VM ; inside there is an SLD editor called "Atlaseditor" https://live.osgeo.org/en/overview/atlasstyler_overview.html. You can use it also.

Hope this helps ;)